# Не удается добавить миграцию в Entity framework code

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

У меня есть такой код

```
internal class Currency
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal BuyPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }

        public bool IsCash { get; set; }
        public int BankId { get; set; }
        public Bank? Bank { get; set; }

        public Currency(string name, decimal buyPrice, decimal sellPrice,bool isCash,Bank? Bank)
        {
            
            this.Name = name;
            this.BuyPrice = buyPrice;
            this.SellPrice = sellPrice;
            this.Bank = Bank;
            this.IsCash = isCash;
        }
    }


internal class Bank
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Currency> Currencies { get; set; } = new();

        public Bank(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
```

При попытке добавить миграцию выдает ошибку

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Currency'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'Bank' in 'Currency(string name, decimal buyPrice, decimal sellPrice, bool isCash, Bank Bank)'.

Ошибка исчезает когда я добавляю пустой конструктор.
Но тогда при выполнении программы выдает ошибку при сохранении изменении

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Banks' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Уберите `Bank? Bank` из параметров. [EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#binding-to-mapped-properties)

Comment: ну добавьте `int BankId` в параметры

Comment: @tym32167 Сработало, спасибо